# react refetch parent component data

Tags: reactjs

I am still trying to get a grasp of the react component life cycle and where/when calls should be made.  I have the following code where I need to update two state elements, based on a child component action which is bound to a parent method.  What is the best way to do this?  I am essentially trying to adhere to putting all my data manipulation and logic in the parent/container as much as possible.

I get the error:  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined(…)`
in the url of the axios call.  I want to know how to address the error and also what is the best way to do this.  Where should I be making my call to refetch the data whenever the selected year is changed?

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import MonthView from './MonthView.js';


class MonthViewContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      selectedYear: 2016
    }

  this.handleAddYear = this.handleAddYear.bind(this);

  this.handleSubtractYear = this.handleSubtractYear.bind(this);

  }

  componentDidMount() {

    var self = this;
    var defaultYear = this.state.selectedYear

       axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/transfilter?year=' + defaultYear + '&grouping=2')
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        self.setState({data: response.data});
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

  }

  render() {
    return <MonthView data={this.state.data} selectedYear={this.state.selectedYear} onAddYear={this.handleAddYear} onSubtractYear={this.handleSubtractYear} />;
  }

  handleAddYear() {
    const newyear = this.state.selectedYear + 1;
    this.setState({selectedYear: newyear}, function () {
      console.log(this.state.selectedYear);
    });
    getTransactions();

  }

  handleSubtractYear() {
    const newyear = this.state.selectedYear - 1;
    this.setState({selectedYear: newyear}, function () {
      console.log(this.state.selectedYear);
    });
    getTransactions();
  }
}

function getTransactions (){    
  var self = this;
  axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/transfilter?year=' + this.state.selectedYear + '&grouping=2')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    self.setState({data: response.data});
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

}

export default MonthViewContainer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTransactions` is not a member function of your `MonthViewContainer` class, and that's why you're getting the `undefined` error: `this` doesn't exist in the scope of the function.

You didn't provide code for `MonthView`, so it's not possible to check whether things in there are right. However, you already have the right idea, by trying to make the container component your "Higher Order Component". It just looks like you're not practised enough yet with coding React components, and just made a minor error.

So for a start, you can try putting `getTransactions()` within the class definition to make it a member function, and then call `this.getTransactions()` from `handleAddYear()`. You will need to bind this to getTransactions as you already do for other event handlers in your constructor.

Also, call `super(props);` rather than just `super()`.

Note as well, that this pattern you are describing is recommended for use in smaller applications. When the number of states and children components who need access to state gets larger, you're advised to apply the [flux pattern](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html).

Comment: Thanks. That worked.  I had set it up that way before, but the issue was that I was not providing the right context for my getTransactions call.   Also, I do plan to switch to a Flux pattern, but since I'm just learning I want to get a solid handle of the basics and make these kinds of mistakes before getting more "advanced".

Comment: I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but what are the negative votes on the question?  Is it because of bad formatting?